# Umbraco custom Data Type - how to hide label?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I am creating a custom Data Type for Umbraco.
It is a UserControl (.ascx file) derived from IUsercontrolDataEditor.
(It shows a grid that lists all the child nodes)

How do I make this control full-width?
ie. I want to hide the label, just like what you can do with RichTextEditor by unchecking 'Show Label'.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers :) Another way to do this is using [AbstractDataEditor](http://www.nibble.be/?p=62), but it is more complicated.

Comment: This question was asked when Umbraco 4 was the latest version - Umbraco 5 had been abandoned & Umbraco 6 was released the following year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a bit of a workaround but should be OK for an admin function (where Name is the label you want to suppress):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.propertyItemheader:contains('Name')").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

For Umbraco 7.x using an angularJs-controller for your custom datatype just change the property hideLabel of the inherited model on the scope:

```
    $scope.model.hideLabel = true;
```

Comment: This question was asked when Umbraco 4 was the latest version - Umbraco 5 had been abandoned & Umbraco 6 was released the following year.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to use some javascript as in [this forum post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/18291-Hide-label-with-usercontrolwrapper#comment68977).